# Stack with a dynamic array: segfaults when popping value multiple times

Tags: c, stack, dynamic-arrays

I have a stack implemented with a dynamically allocated array, which is populated using scanf(). The push function works properly, except that when I print out the stack, I always get two extra zeros at the beginning of the output. Attempting to pop the stack only pops the zeroes, and it segfaults once the popping happens twice. I can't figure out where this issue is occurring.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    /*Creates struct of stack*/
    typedef struct Stack{
        int *ptArray;
        int top;
        int stackSize;
        int itemsInStack;
    } Stack;

    /*Initialized stack*/
    Stack*  stackInit(){
        Stack *a;
        a= (Stack*) malloc(sizeof(Stack));
        a-> ptArray=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)) ;
        a-> top=0;
        a-> stackSize=1;
        return a;
    }

    void stackPush(  Stack *stx, int val){

        if( (stx->top) == (stx->stackSize)){ 
            grow(&stx->ptArray, &stx->stackSize);
        } 
        stx->ptArray[stx->top]= val;
        stx->top++; 
        stx->itemsInStack++;
    }
    /*Grows astack array when space runs out*/
    void grow(int** array, int *sz){
        int *temp;
        temp= (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)* (*sz+2) );
        int i;
        for( i=0; i< *sz; i++)
            temp[i]=( *array)[i];
        free(*array);
        *array= temp;
        *sz=*sz+2;
    }

    void stackPop( Stack* stx){
        free(stx->ptArray[stx->top]);
        stx->top--;
        stx->stackSize--;
        stx->itemsInStack--;

    }

    void showStack(Stack* s){
        int i;
        printf("\n");
        for(i=s->stackSize; i>-1; i--){
            printf("%d\n", s->ptArray[i]);
        }
    }

    void main(int argc, char** argv){

    Stack *stackArray;
    stackArray= stackInit();

        int val=0;
        while (val != -999) {
            scanf("%d", &val);
            if (val == -999) {
                break;
            }
            stackPush(stackArray, val);
        }

        showStack(stackArray);
        stackPop(stackArray);
        stackPop(stackArray);
        showStack(stackArray);
        stackPop(stackArray);
        showStack(stackArray);

    }
```

Comment: See [ask]. Use a debugger to get the specific problem.

Comment: `int *temp;`
 `temp= (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)* (*sz+2) );` why are you casting it to a char* ?

Comment: that was a mistake, it should be int

Comment: you have to allocate `int` aswell, not `char`

Comment: `grow(&stx->ptArray, &stx->stackSize);` here array is already a pointer, you can just say `grow(stx->ptArray, &stx->stackSize)` and then `void grow(int* array, int *sz)` and then use normal array notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in your malloc / free couples.

You allocate the array like this :

```
 a-> ptArray=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)) ;
```

If you need to grow the stack you allocate a new array like this :

```
 temp= (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)* (*sz+2) );
```

So you allocate the whole array at one.

But for some reasons , when you are poping an item you do this :

```
 free(stx->ptArray[stx->top]);
```

You never allocated this. you allocated ptArray so if you have to free something , it is ptArray.

Just like you did in your grow function :

```
  free(*array);
```

I hope your error is clear now.This is what is causing the segmentation fault. However you still have some issues with the management of your stack.

Comment: That fixes that immediate issue- thanks so much. You're right, I still have to manage it better.